# Creating Web Interface with R and Shiny to upload CSV files then download after filtering some column names,

Tags: r, shiny

How I can build web interface to upload CSV files then filter the column names into select option 6 "as described in shiny gallery", the result from selection creating new view then download it as another CSV file,

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples in the Shiny docs that demonstrate almost exactly what you're looking for:

**Upload a CSV file**

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

**Download a CSV file**

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-download.html

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "bind the column name into drop down menu then export the output". If you can provide an example, I'll add a more specific demo app to the answer.